# iOS Sliding Puzzle in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a sliding tile puzzle app for my senior design project.  The app consists of selecting or taking a photo (which I have figured out), then having the app cut the image into 9 pieces (cropped images) and store them in an array, then remove one, and display them in a random order on the screen. Finally, the user touches or slides the tiles around until they're arranged in the correct order.

I've found various examples of code online, but none written in Swift. When I try to interpret the older code I've found and re-write it in Swift, I get all kinds of errors... I'm a student newbie with all of this.

I've been trying to use CGSizeMake, CGRectMake, and CGImageCreateWithImageInRect to create new cropped images from the user-selected image that is displayed in the displayImageView, and then store those new cropped image pieces in the tileStack array. But, I think I'm missing something... perhaps I'm missing a lot.

Here's a [screenshot of the error when I run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iImP0.png).
[image]

```
//PhotoViewController.swift Created by Jim on 2/18/16. Copyright © 2016 JamesDphoto.com. All rights reserved.

import UIKit import Foundation

class PhotoViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var tileStack = [AnyObject]();

     //Beginning of simple image selection and display     
    @IBOutlet weak var displayImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func choosePicFromLibrary(sender: AnyObject) {
        let imagePicker: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover

        if (imagePicker.popoverPresentationController != nil) {
            imagePicker.popoverPresentationController!.sourceView = sender as! UIButton
            imagePicker.popoverPresentationController!.sourceRect = (sender as! UIButton).bounds
        }
        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }   
    @IBAction func takePhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
        let imagePicker: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover

        if (imagePicker.popoverPresentationController != nil) {
            imagePicker.popoverPresentationController!.sourceView = sender as! UIButton
            imagePicker.popoverPresentationController!.sourceRect = (sender as! UIButton).bounds
        }
        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        displayImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage!
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }


     //Beginning of function to cut photo into 9 tiles, then randomize them.

    //cut into 9 tiles and add to tileStack array
    @IBAction func randomize(sender: AnyObject) {

    let tileSize = CGSizeMake(displayImageView.image!.size.width/3, displayImageView.image!.size.height/3)

        for var rowI = 0; rowI < 3; rowI++
        {
            for var colI = 0; colI < 3; colI++
            {
                let tileRect = CGRectMake(CGFloat(rowI) * tileSize.width, tileSize.height * CGFloat(colI), tileSize.width, tileSize.height)

                let tileImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(displayImageView.image as! CGImage!, tileRect)
                tileStack.append(tileImage!)
            }
        }   
        //display tiles in order on screen
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: You should post the error in plain text, not links to images of the error.  You should also be getting a message in the console (probably fatal error found nil when unwrapping)

Comment: For one thing, there's no need for `CGRectMake`, `CGSizeMake`, etc. in swift, just use the constructors: `CGSize(width: , height: )`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips on posting, nhgrif!

Comment: Thanks, David Berry! I will try to figure out how to eliminate unnecessary code, and just use the CGSize...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to convert a UIImage object to CGImage implicitly. Thats why your app is crashing, try this only if you are sure the displaImageView.image is not nil.

```
let tileImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(displayImageView.image!.CGImage, tileRect)
```

I would prefer

```
if let dpimage = displayImageView.image
{
 let tileImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(dpimage.CGImage, tileRect)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, shinoys222! I'll give this a try.

Comment: I posted a new question with new code - wasn't sure if/how I could continue in this thread since this comment section has a character limit... If you can take a look, that'd be great!